# xtext - creating a new EObject

Tags: eclipse-emf, xtext

I want to create a new `EObject`, but by default the constructor is protected.
Is there a way to overcome that and create a new instance of `EObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EMF uses the factory pattern. Please try `EcoreFactory.eInstance.createEObject()`.

If you want to instantiate other objects that implement EObject, you'll have to use the respective factory for your own EPackage. The code should read `MyPackFactory.eInstance.createObject()` where `MyPackFactory` should be replaced by your concrete factory and `createObject()` has to be replaced by the type that you want to instantiate, e.g. `createObjectValue()`

Comment: I have another question related to this one, in my xtext i generate objects that implementing EObject (like ObjectValue).
Is it possible to generate a new ObjectValue? 

the code:
ObjectValue value = (ObjectValue) EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEObject();
is failing to cast.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited the answer and added some information for your use case.

Comment: do you know where can I read about it? 
http://www.vogella.com/code/EMFEncrypt/src/codestartpage.html
I tried to follow this example but, couldn't suit it to my project

Comment: You may want to follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html